# how to save simple CRUD codes in a service, just like GenericDao/JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

Our web project uses spring3, Jpa (hibernate).

To save CRUD and other commonly used methods, we made our repositories sub-classes of spring JpaRepository.

Sometimes I just injected repositories to Controller, it is convenient for those simple (or none) business logic read-only data access. e.g. list all objects of an entity type in view... I knew that all these should be done in a service layer with transaction scope, but it is really convenient.

Now comes a rule:  controller layer must via Service access data layer. Injecting Repositories into Controller is not allowed.

for example:

I have an Entity: `Country.java`

And I have `interface  CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long>`

Also I have CountryService and CountryServiceImpl, which has countryRepository injected. Then I have to create findAll, findOne, count, findAll(with sorting).... methods, and those implementation is nothing more than `return countryRepository.findAll() countryRepository.findOne(id) countryRepository.count()...`

And for each entity I have to do the same again and again...

Is it possible that in service layer save those methods using a generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only expose services that your application really uses. I doubt you need a `findAll` or a `count` for every entity.

The fact that the implementation of these methods is very simple is a good thing: you won't have any difficulty implementing and testing them. If they become more complex, and need several repository method calls and a bit of business logic, you'll be happy to just have to modify the method, and not change all your design.

Comment: I don't need findAll for all, but I do need findOne for >90% cases. And for some domain data, maybe we just need two methods (findone and findAll). however we have to create 1 interface and 1 serviceImpl, and "repeat" the repository methods in it. would be good to save some codes.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a service for every entity. I usually have a service per use-case, or per logical set of use-cases. For example: a service for client management, another one for product management, etc. But in the service for product management, I will manage products, categories, prices, etc. And in client management, I will manage clients, their addresses, their contacts, etc. This saves some classes and dependencies. Services are there to implement business logic, and not single entity-related stuff.

Comment: i agree with your service opinion.  but the handy repository methods are repeated in service anyway.