# Spring Data - one service class to handle common operations on entities (how to autowire JpaRepository)

Tags: java, generics, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Main question** - I want to write a service (say CommonService) to handle common operations like find, count etc. for a range of entities (there is a reason why I cant use the JpaRepository out-of-box methods as explained below). How can I autowire a JpaRepository to achieve this? Details -

**Complication** - Now, due to business requirements, I have to associate a country ID with every entity (while saving, and use while retrieving etc.). I get this ID from the logged in user (i.e. not provided as part of saving or querying the entity) - so I cannot use (or expose via REST) the JpaRepository save or findOne directly - I have to go thru a service that does this and then saves/fetches using the JpaRepository.

**Tech Stack**

1. Spring data jpa 1.9.4
2. Spring boot 1.3.5
3. JPA provider hibernate
4. DB - MySQL

I have an abstract Base Entity - Fruit (with @MappedSuperclass) that all my fruit classes extend - e.g. Apple, Orange etc.

I have a BaseRepository for common methods -

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
  /* common entity methods here */
  T findByIdAndCountryId(Long id, String countryId);
  Long countByIdAndCountryId(Long id, String countryId);
}
```

That all the Fruit repositories extend -

```
public interface AppleRepository extends BaseRepository<Apple> {
  /* entity specific methods here */
}

public interface OrangeRepository extends BaseRepository<Orange> {
  /* entity specific methods here */
}

public interface BananaRepository extends BaseRepository<Banana> {
  /* entity specific methods here */
}

public interface GrapeRepository extends BaseRepository<Grape> {
  /* entity specific methods here */
}
```

Now, due to business requirements (menthined in complication above), I have to have a service layer that does the save/fetche using the JpaRepository. Something like below -

```
public Fruit findMyFruit(Long id) {
    Fruit localFruit;
    String countryId = null;

    countryId = countryService.GetCountryIdForLoggedInUser();

    /* ?? how to autowire repository based on entity ?? */
    repository.findByIdAndCountryId(id, countryId);

    return localBaseEntity;
}
```

In the case above, it is just about getting the countryId, other cases are more complicated hence I cannot (or do not want to) repeat them every time in the calling Controllers or services etc.

If I use Generics and do the following, Spring does not like it -

```
public class CommonService<Fruit>{
  @Autowired
  BaseRepository<Fruit> repository;
}
```

it gives the error -

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4

One way that I can make it work (what I have currently done), is to pass the Entity to every method in the CommonService, which then uses the appropriate repository based on the entity type passed (using instanceof) - clearly this is not the most efficient way -

```
    switch (determineEntityType(incomingFruit)) {
        case APPLE:
            localFruit = appleRepository.findByIdAndCountryId(id, countryId);
            break;
        case ORANGE:
            localFruit = orangeRepository.findByIdAndCountryId(id, countryId);
            break;
        case BANANA:
            localFruit = bananaRepository.findByIdAndCountryId(id, countryId);
            break;
        case GRAPE:
            localFruit = grapeRepository.findByIdAndCountryId(id, countryId);
            break;
        default:
            /* throwing UnrecognizedFruitException */
    }
```

There are couple other similar questions on SO, but no answers / solutions so far - e.g.

1. [Spring data: Autowire JpaRepository (Generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154382/spring-data-autowire-jparepository-generic-type)
2. [how to save simple CRUD codes in a service, just like GenericDao/JpaRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658899/how-to-save-simple-crud-codes-in-a-service-just-like-genericdao-jparepository)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you know in advance which kind of `Fruit` you will get from `findMyFruit(id)`? And can there be two fruits of different kind with equal ids?

Comment: In CommonService, no, I don't know in advance (if I were to write individual services e.g. AppleService, OrangeService, I can know in advance - but not using CommonService). 

Also, all Fruits have unique IDs regardless of kind (no two will have same - whether of the same kind or not). Hope this elaborates.